# How can I remove "Watch on Youtube" from Gutenberg embed editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

How can I remove "Watch on Youtube" when I use Gutenberg editor Youtube embed block. When this way, on the lower left side there is a stripe written "Watch on Youtube", which does not match the content and I believe it makes the user leave the site easier.

I tried to pass the parameters known by the url that solve this question, but Gutemberg does not accept anything in the url informed in the field.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to hide the "Watch on Youtube" link is via CSS:

**style.css**

```css
.ytp-impression-link{
    display:none;
}
```

This doesn't change the underlying block structure or cause validation issues and the link is "gone".

Comment: It didn't work, I added it to my css, and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @S.Walsh is actualy correct.
Since it's not working for you, you can check if you are adding this stye in your global css file. To be extra sure, you can also add the `!important` flag.

**global-styles.css**

```css
.ytp-impression-link{
   display: none !important;
}
```

*I could have just commented this. But since I do not have enough reputation, I have posted this answer.*

Comment: Nope. It's not working again. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: It's not working, I think, because of the delay to load components of YouTube, the component load after the CSS.